# How to log an already trained Tensorflow model in MLFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, mlflow

I am trying to log a Tensorflow model which I have loaded with `model = tf.saved_model.load(my_model_directory)`. I am getting an error when I call `mlflow.tensorflow.log_model(model, "model")`

In the MLFlow FAQ they have [an example](https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-resources/blob/master/MLflow_FAQ.md#how-do-i-create-an-mlflow-run-from-a-model-i-have-trained-elsewhere) of doing this exact same thing with a Keras model.

```
import mlflow
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("tf_keras_model")
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    mlflow.keras.log_model(model, "model")
```

I have tried this with a Tensorflow model:

```
imported: AutoTrackable = tf.saved_model.load(my_model_directory)
inference_function: WrappedFunction = imported.signatures["serving_default"]

mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    #mlflow.tensorflow.log_model(imported, "model")
    mlflow.tensorflow.log_model(inference_function, "model")
```

Running this gives the errors

> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Unknown model type: <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction'>

or

> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Unknown model type: <class 'tensorflow.python.trackable.autotrackable.AutoTrackable'>

The MLFlow [documentation for the `.log_model()` function](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tensorflow.html#mlflow.tensorflow.log_model) says the first argument should be "TF2 core model (inheriting tf.Module) or a Keras model in MLflow Model format." How can I get something I can log from the AutoTrackable that I get from `tf.saved_model.load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because the object returned by `tf.saved_model.load()` isn't directly a TensorFlow 2 core model (inheriting `tf.Module`) or a Keras model, which is what `mlflow.tensorflow.log_model()` expects. Instead, `tf.saved_model.load()` returns an `AutoTrackable` object, which is a more generic representation of serialized TensorFlow objects.

To log the model with MLflow, you can follow these steps:

1. **Convert the SavedModel to a ConcreteFunction**: This will allow you to obtain a callable TensorFlow function from the loaded model, which can be used to make predictions.
2. **Create a Custom tf.Module**: TensorFlow 2.x encourages the use of `tf.Module` for encapsulating models. Since MLflow expects a `tf.Module` or a Keras model, you can create a custom module and add the `ConcreteFunction` to it.
3. **Log the Custom tf.Module with MLflow**: Now that you have a `tf.Module`, you can log it using MLflow.

Here's how you can implement these steps:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import mlflow

# Load the SavedModel
imported = tf.saved_model.load(my_model_directory)

# Convert the SavedModel to a ConcreteFunction
inference_function = imported.signatures["serving_default"]

# Create a custom tf.Module
class CustomModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, inference_function):
        self.inference_function = inference_function

    @tf.function(input_signature=inference_function.input_signature)
    def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.inference_function(*args, **kwargs)

# Create an instance of the custom module with the inference function
module_instance = CustomModule(inference_function)

# Log the model with MLflow
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    mlflow.tensorflow.log_model(module_instance, "model")
```

This approach wraps the ConcreteFunction within a custom tf.Module and should satisfy the requirement for logging with MLflow.

References:

[TensorFlow 2 SavedModel documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model)

[MLflow TensorFlow documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tensorflow.html)